# Run multiple C++ files using Code Runner extension VS Code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, vscode-code-runner

I have been using Code Runner for one single C++ file. However, I'm having issues when I try to compile more than one file together using the extension. As I read in [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791972/coderunner-and-multiple-file-projects) and in other forums, the extension automatically reads the include statements and compiles all the necesary files if they are in the same folder. I don't know why that isn't working in my case. This is the extension configuration (I put the entire settings.json just in case):

```
"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {

        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "zig": "zig run",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runghc",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName",
        "mojo": "mojo run"
    },
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++",
    "code-runner.enableAppInsights": false,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

This is the file I was tring to compile ('func.h' is in the same folder):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    print();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
cc301Ipx.o:tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `print()'
```

I tried changing the extension configuration but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I would suggest to not, and instead start learning cmake or meson or some other build system.